# Basic javascript mouseOver and mouseOut script being glitchy

Tags: javascript, html, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm trying to make a basic javascript effect, where when you hover over a thumbnail, the thumbnail will fadeTo a .5 opacity, and an overlaying div will appear. I have the effect in place, but for some reason the script is buggy and the animation lags. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

My script:

Html

```
<div class="thumbnailholder">
    <div class="thumbnaildesc">
            Lester Beall poster blah blah
    </div>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="img.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    <script>

$('.thumbnailholder')

.mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.thumbnaildesc').fadeIn(400);
    $(this).find('img.thumbnail').fadeTo("fast", 0.5); })

.mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.thumbnaildesc').stop(true).fadeOut(400);
    $(this).find('img.thumbnail').stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 1); })


</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have .fadeIn(400) and .fadeOut(400), that is probably why it seems "laggy"

Comment: before you get too far down the road, consider using CSS for this sort of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just animate the opacity, to prevent problems with `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` and `fadeTo`. These problems occur, because `fadeOut` results in a `display: none`, which does a little more then hiding. In fact, `display: none` disables further user interaction with the element and virtually removes it from the DOM. So things might get glitchy.

Transitioning with `.animate()` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)):

```
$('.thumbnailholder')
.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.thumbnaildesc').animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    $(this).find('img.thumbnail').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 400);
})
.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.thumbnaildesc').animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
    $(this).find('img.thumbnail').animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noL3e4w9/)

As [Simon H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1923190/simon-h) mentioned: A pure CSS solution would more performant, especially, if you have a lot of thumbnails:

```
.thumbnailholder {
    position: relative; 
}
.thumbnailholder img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnailholder:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}
.thumbnailholder p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.thumbnailholder:hover p {
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noL3e4w9/1/)